Permissions in manifest don't show up in app info
I have specified the needed app's permissions, but they don't show up in the app info area in Settings, and of course the permission request call doesn't produce any request pop-up.
Manifest merge doesn't show any conflicts. I have invalidated caches and Sync'd gradle files many times already.
I don't know what else to do to get this working.
enter image description here
I have tried to invalidate cache, re-sync gradle files and add tags to the uses-permission xml entries, and was expecting the permissions to show up on the app's info area in Settings, but didn't get it.
I'll add the whole manifest below:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SET_WALLPAPER"/>


    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:dataExtractionRules="@xml/data_extraction_rules"
        android:fullBackupContent="@xml/backup_rules"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.FondoFinal"
        tools:targetApi="31">
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>


You should use either of them ...
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_MEDIA_LOCATION" />

ACCESS_MEDIA_LOCATION is a permission introduced in Android 10 (API level 29) to access the location information embedded in media files (like photos and videos) stored on the device.

Or

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_MEDIA_IMAGES" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_MEDIA_AUDIO" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_MEDIA_VIDEO" />

These are the primary permissions that have replaced the older READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE
android.permission.READ_MEDIA_IMAGES: This permission allows your app to read images and videos from external storage.
android.permission.READ_MEDIA_AUDIO: This permission grants access to audio files on external storage.
android.permission.READ_MEDIA_VIDEO: This permission enables your app to read video files from external storage.

I found the answer and made it work!!
I didn't say it in my OP, but I should've specified I'm targetting android 12 (api 31), and that demands some legacy-oriented tweaking of the manifest.
In the android developer docs it is specified you have to declare your needed permissions as follows:
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" android:maxSdkVersion="32" />

That solved the problem and now the permission is both requested at runtime and listed in the app info area in settings.
